# MaintainJ with "Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher plugin"

Tags: java, reverse-engineering

I am using eclipse with tomcat server plug in from the "Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher plugin".

Now i want use Maintainj with my configuration(Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher plugin) please help me to configure any one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add MaintainJ.war to the Tomcat and follow the instructions of the wizard. After Step 2, you will see the instructions to add to the server classpath and to the JVM arguments. You will have to manually do those changes to complete MaintainJ's configuration.